# Entity Relationship (ER) Diagram enum values

Tags: class, enums, entity-relationship, diagram

As far as I know, we can show enum values in Class Diagrams as shown below:

```
----------------------+
|   <<enumeration>>   |
|    DayOfTheWeek     |
|_____________________|
| Sunday              |
| Monday              |
| Tuesday             |
| ...                 |
+---------------------+
```

```
+---------------------+
|        Event        |
|_____________________|
| day : DayOfTheWeek  |
| ...                 |
+---------------------+
```

However, I cannot find any representation for showing enum values in ER Diagrams. So, how to show enum in ER Diagrams with the proper relation types?

Comment: There is no enum in an ERD

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks a lot Senior. Then I remove all of the enum classes from my ERD, right?

Comment: Yes you can remove it

Answer (score 1):

#### What is an enum?

An enumeration corresponds to a set of values that are each represented by a literal, which is more convenient to deal with.  In your example, you'd work with `Sunday..Saturday`  whereas you could, if needed, also work with an integer `0..6`, which is less convenient.

#### What about enum types in ERD?

While ERD mostly use  familiar types of known DBMS systems, the theoretical definition of an attribute [according to P.Chen](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/320434.320440), the inventor or ERD, is much broader:

> An attribute can be formally defined as a function which maps from an entity set or a relationship set into a value set or a Cartesian product of value sets.

So you could very well use attributes of a home-grown enum type. It's just that ERD does not provide any convenient way to describe the set of possible literal values.  You'd probably have to describe these in a comment box or outside the diagram.

#### What's the better ERD-native equivalent?

An enum such as `DayOfTheWeek` in reality just uniquely identifies a named value.  You could model the same with an entity `DayOfTheWeek`  with the following values:

```
+---------------------+
|    DayOfTheWeek     |
|---------------------|
| Id   |  Day         |
|------+--------------|
| 0    |  Sunday      |
| 1    |  Monday      |
| 2    |  Tuesday     |
| ...  |  ..          |
+---------------------+
```

Such enum-entities have many advantages:

- Abstraction from the enum values whenever possible
- Easy enrichment with new enum values whenever needed
- Easy localisation of the code, e.g. replacing the days with their translation in local language
- Easy internationalisation,  by adding Day name in several languages.
- Efficient OOP-like comparison/matching based on numerical `id` with the extended power of relational algebra in queries
- High consistency: those enums attributes are used as easily as any other attribute in any relational queries, including with third party tools that would have direct access to the database.